# running a spark application fails on EC2 with hadoop IncompatibleClassChangeError

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, amazon-ec2

I have a simple spark application, and it runs ok on my laptop using `spark-submit`.
However, I get this runtime error when I run it using `spark-submit` on a Amazon EC2 cluster:

```
$ /root/spark/bin/spark-submit --class application.Example --master spark://ec2-54-227-170-20.compute-1.amazonaws.com:7077 /root/example-assembly-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar 

java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found class org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext, but interface was expected
    at org.warcbase.mapreduce.WacGenericInputFormat$GenericArchiveRecordReader.initialize(WacGenericInputFormat.java:71)
```

I made sure that `/root/example-assembly-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` does not contain `org/apache/spark` nor `org/apache/hadoop`.

I am using spark 1.6.1 and hadoop 2.6.0. I see that [warcbase](https://github.com/lintool/warcbase/blob/master/pom.xml) depends on hadoop 2.6.0-cdh5.7.1.

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that my local installation of `spark` and also the `warcbase` library use`hadoop 2.6.0`, and the spark installation at amazon ec2 uses `hadoop 1.2.1`.

So, on my laptop I have `spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6`. I run `spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/ec2/spark-ec2`, which deploys a spark cluster at amazon ec2. I would expect that it deploys the same version, but it actually deploys `spark-assembly-1.6.1-hadoop1.2.1.jar`. Pretty dump.

---

so, when executing spark-ec2 to create the spark cluster on amazon ec2, you need to specify the spark and hadoop version (it won't use the ones of your local installation). For some reason hadoop version 2.6.0 is not available.

```
$ spark-ec2 --help
Usage: spark-ec2 [options] <action> <cluster_name>

<action> can be: launch, destroy, login, stop, start, get-master, reboot-slaves

Options:
...
  -v SPARK_VERSION, --spark-version=SPARK_VERSION
                        Version of Spark to use: 'X.Y.Z' or a specific git
                        hash (default: 1.6.1)
...
  --hadoop-major-version=HADOOP_MAJOR_VERSION
                        Major version of Hadoop. Valid options are 1 (Hadoop
                        1.0.4), 2 (CDH 4.2.0), yarn (Hadoop 2.4.0) (default:
                        1)
...


$ spark-ec2 --key-pair=test-us-east-1 --identity-file=~/.ssh/test-us-east-1.pem --instance-type=m3.xlarge --slaves=10 -v 1.6.1 --region=us-east-1 launch my-spark-cluster --spark-version=1.6.1 --hadoop-major-version=2.4.0
```